# What is a good approach for a /forgot route to respond?

Tags: node.js, express

So when you are responding (server-side) to a `/forgot-password` route what is the best response to it? ( In the situation that you don't want to expose what users you have in the DB and still hint the app that the user does not exist)

I was faced today with this scenario in which I respond in that route with 200 but my colleague that is working on his app wanted me to send an error so he could implement an SMS recovery form.

Imagine this:

```
POST /forget-password
Body: { username: 'test' }
```

And you respond with 404/400 and an error message like:

```
{
 statusCode: 404,
 message: 'User not found'
}
```

Is this a good practice? Or not?

Why I am asking this? When you are responding to a client with 404 you expose what usernames you have in your database and this might be a security breach.

What is the best approach for this, and why?

In my opinion, I'm guessing that you should respond with 200, in either case, to not let any kind of scenarios for the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had it correct at the beginning.  You should return an HTTP 200.  This is to prevent someone from looping through with various usernames to figure out who exists, etc.

What I typically do is accept whatever they put in, then email the provided information either a "sorry, that account doesn't exist, create one here" or "here's your link to reset your password".